# JSON Adding values to a class

Tags: json, vb.net

Kind of new (inexperienced)  to JSON.  I'm trying to add an accessorial code in my project. Example codes is "HAZ".

I've created a public class for Accessorials (see below)   and in that class I have "Public codes As String()".

```
Public Class Accessorials
    Public codes As String()
    Public hazardousContact As HazardousContact
    Public cod As Object
    Public insuranceDetails As Object
    Public sortAndSegregateDetails As Object
    Public markDetails As Object
End Class
```

Which in turn feeds the primary Wrapper

```
Public Class fgtload 'Primary wrapper
    Public service As New fgtservice
    Public payment As New fgtpayment
    Public transit As New fgttransit
    Public commodities As New List(Of Items)
    Public origin As New fgtorigin
    Public destination As New fgtdestination
    Public billTo As New fgtbillto
    **Public accessorials As New Accessorials**
End Class
```

I'm trying to add the code "HAZ"  to the class Accessorials.
which shows the code as "  Public codes As String()"
I'm assuming by the () that it's looking for an array of sorts.
Should (within the primary wrapper)  accessorials be a List(Of Accessorials)  ?

The outcome should be :

```
"accessorials" : {
    "codes" : [ "HAZ" ],
    "hazardousContact" : {
    "name" : "John Snow",
    "phone" : "7704865900"
},
```

Here's the full JSON from the API Guide

```
{"service":{"level":"STND"},"payment":{"terms":"Prepaid","payer":"Shipper"},"transit":{"pickupDate":"20230930"},"commodities":[{"classification":"92.5","weight":"1500","length":"48","width":"40","height":"40","pieces":"3","packagingType":"PAT","description":"Umbrellas","stackable":"Y"},{"classification":"50","weight":"50","length":"48","width":"48","height":"48","pieces":"5","packagingType":"PAT","description":"Soda","stackable":"N"}],"accessorials":{"codes":["HAZ"],"hazardousContact":{"name":"John Snow","phone":"7704865900"},"cod":null,"insuranceDetails":null,"sortAndSegregateDetails":null,"markDetails":null},"origin":{"account":"1234567","city":"LEBANON","stateProvince":"TN","postalCode":"37090","country":"USA"},"destination":{"account":"","city":"Calgary","stateProvince":"AB","postalCode":"T1Y2S2","country":"CAN"},"billTo":{"account":"","name":"Bill To Company","address":"456 Bill Me Rd.","city":"LEBANON","stateProvince":"TN","postalCode":"37090","country":"USA"}}
```

Comment: You probably need to explain your question a lot more.  You talk about a class for Accessorials, then give use the definition for a heap of other classes, how exactly are they related to the question.  You've got a _get_data_ object in there with no info on what it is doing.  Maybe some some json data you're attempting to handle might help?  Finally, if your end goal is to use a DB, what is purpose this json?

Comment: @Tu deschizi eu inchid  and 2020 was the last time I used JSON.  I used a JSON class generator and formatter to complete the project. I mainly do desktop apps, some web and use xml/rest/and URL requests.  And now I have another project that requires JSON. So yeah I'm kind of sorta still new at it. Perhaps I should have said "still inexperienced. "

Comment: @Hursey  Hi, I've trimmed down the code and added some more that was focused on the issue.   I'd be content if I could just get the code "HAZ" added to the JSON accessorial area. I can't seem to create the object for the array correctly.

Comment: The following may be of interest [JSON Utils](https://jsonutils.com/).

Comment: @Tu deschizi eu inchid  Yes thank you.   That's where i used the class generator the other day.  I'm just having issues creating the object to store the accessorial codes.

Comment: What is the source of this json?  Are you able to update your question with the code to receive this json, then deserialize?  Should be just a case of getting that right, then it's simply a combo of linq and property values

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the following wouldn't work?

```
Dim f = new fgtload
ReDim Preserve f.accessorials.codes(f.accessorials.codes.Length)
f.accessorials.codes(f.accessorials.codes.Length - 1) = "HAZ"
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for you response.  Where did you get that "f"   from in f.accessorials  ?

Comment: Apologies, the `f` is your `fgtload` class. I have updated my answer

Comment: that was my guess :).  I had already declared "Load as new fgtload"  at the top of my code.  So I swapped Load for your f.   

    ReDim Preserve Load.accessorials.codes(Load.accessorials.codes.Length)
        Load.accessorials.codes(Load.accessorials.codes.Length - 1) = "HAZ"

Now I'm receiving an error : 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'   Using you submission or my modified of yours.

Answer (score 0):

The resolution was:

Load.accessorials.codes = New List(Of String)
Load.accessorials.codes.Add("IDL")
-Or use this
Load.accessorials.codes = New List(Of String)({"IDL"})

Also seems the code I was actually using, from the actual API Guide ,was invalid, i.e. a typo. I've contacted their web support and reported the typo.  Once I started using the correct code I was able to process the JSON without error.

I found that the code was bad by further consuming the
httpresponse using :

```
  Dim sReader = New StreamReader(webExcp.Response.GetResponseStream)
        Dim result = sReader.ReadToEnd
        result = result
```

By doing so I saw the error about the submitted code being invalid.
I wasn't aware of the capability of consuming a greater error code as such. I normally just snagged the stats and simple message.  Live and learn. Anyway I'm good now. Thanks for all your inputs.